# regex - capture type specifiers in format string

Tags: regex, escaping, string-formatting

Consider a `printf`-like function's `format` argument. Something like:

```
printf("Hello %s, your rating is %i%%", name, percentage);
```

I want to use regex to capture all the type specifiers (in the above case, `%s` and `%i` *and not* `%%`).

I've started with a naïve `(%[^%])` pattern, but it wrongly captures things like `%%f` instead of "escaping" it. Off course, `%%%f` should be interpreted as an escaped "%" and then a specifier.

I figured I need some more complex pattern (maybe lookbehind?), but could not sort it out. Any suggestions?

Side note: I know my pattern does not handle length specifiers and other formatting flags such as `%2f` etc., but that's fine with me since my goal is mainly to enumerate and count the format specifiers.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify more what your intentions are.  Why are you doing this?  Do you need to use regex, or can you do some string parsing ( e.g. find and remove the escaped characters ) ?

Comment: Ultimately, the goal is to write a set convenient wrapper functions around `printf`, `sprintf`, `NSLog` etc. that replaces wrong specifiers, handles objc object description formatting and more. I can iterate the char array by hand and tokenize the format string, but regex would make the code much cleaner.

Comment: I'm thinking iterating by hand might end up being the cleaner and better option.  I'm not a regex wizard, but I'm ok.  If it needs to be written by a regex wizard then it might be making things more complicated than you want.

Comment: Note, the gcc compiler will already check `printf()` and other stdlib format strings at compile time with `-Wformat`. If you have your own `myprintf()` using similar arguments you can add `__attribute__ ((format (printf,...)))` to it and it will be checked too.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! can I somehow control this compiler warning evaluation? Or create my own `__attribute__ ((format (myprintf,...))) `? I want to ignore, for instance, wrong `%@` since my wrapper should convert an objective c object (with `%@` as type specifier) to a c string description, and change the format to `%s`.

Comment: I've found this: https://github.com/atelierdumobile/LOG_EXPR. It does pretty much what I needed (logging and variable without worrying about it's type). I will edit it to do `sprintf` functionality and embed it into my code.

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, you can't skip characters without accidentally catching things like `%%f`, so you have to either use `match` or put a `^` (caret) in the beginning of your regex. On the other hand, in this case you can't use `findall`. Since there's no `matchall` function, the simplest will be to write your own loop:

```
REG = re.compile('([^%]|%%)*(%[^%])')  # a bunch of (non-% or %%), and then (% followed by non-%).
def find_type_specifiers(st):
    retval = []
    pos = 0  # where to start searching for next time
    while True:
        match = REG.match(st, pos)
        if match is None:
            return retval
        retval.append(match.group(2))
        pos = match.end()
```

Of course, you can change what you append to `retval` if e.g. you're also interested in locations of specifiers. Or change to a counter if you only want the amount.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the general case PCRE for regex's based on ["official" documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

```
\%[0 #+-]?[0-9*]*\.?\d*[hl]{0,2}[jztL]?[diuoxXeEfgGaAcpsSn%]
```

Technically [hl]{0,2} cannot precede [jztL] so if you want to be more strict then use this:

```
\%[0 #+-]?[0-9*]*\.?\d*([hl]{0,2}|[jztL])?[diuoxXeEfgGaAcpsSn%]
```

Also not all length specifiers (hljztL) work with all format specifiers so the regex is a bit looser than necesary, but still sufficient in most cases.  For example %Ls is at least meaningless, possibly invalid.